# Get data once from 2 observables

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, angularfire2

I have 2 observables, and I need to get each observable data only one time.

What I did is subscription inside a subscription, although they can be executed in the same time (in parallel).

```
let table = this.af.database.object('tables');
    table.subscribe((tableData) => {
      let section_seats =  this.af.database.object('sections').take(1)
      .subscribe((sectionData) => {
          //Here I'm Using tableData  & sectionData
});
});
```

The code above works great, but they are not executed in the same time although they can.

How I can execute both of the observables in the same time then use the data received from both of them?

**Update: Using forkJoin() doing nothing (no console log from the following code)**

```
var source = Observable.forkJoin(
  this.af.database.object('tables'),
  this.af.database.object('sections')
);

var subscription = source.subscribe(
  function (x) {
    console.log('Next: %s', x);
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log('Error: %s', err);
  },
  function () {
    console.log('Completed');
  });
```

Comment: Have you done any research on this? How about https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md

Comment: When I'm using forkJoin on this, nothing is executed, I have no clue why..

Comment: `forkJoin` is what you want, please provide the code. Did you subscribe?

Comment: @AlexanderCiesielski Take a look at my update, I tried to use forkJoin like that, and no console logs like nothing happens.

Comment: You have to add `.take(1)` after the inner Observables, since forkJoin fires only after all inner Observables have completed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways (read, operators) which will help you combine sources. A general resource can be found [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/categories.md), in the section `Combining multiple observable sequences into a single sequence`. For your specific problem, here is the short list that seems to make the cut :

- [combineLatest](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/combinelatest.md): emits a value when 1. BOTH sources have emitted at least one value, 2. after that, anytime one of the sources emits a value.

For example: `Rx.Observable.combineLatest(object('tables'), object('sections').take(1))`

- withLatestFrom : emits a value when the first source emits a value. The emitted value includes the latest emitted value of the second source.

For example : `object('tables').withLatesFrom(object('sections').take(1))`

- [zip](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/zip.md) : emits first value when BOTH sources have emitted one value. emits Nth value via the same process.

For example: `Rx.Observable.zip(object('tables'), object('sections').take(1))`

Each of those operators have similar but slightly different semantics. I would assume `combineLatest` is what you need but check the doc, set up some code and try out something and if that does not work, come back and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `withLatestFrom` operator.

see here more on [withLatestFrom](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/withlatestfrom.md)

```
/* Have staggering intervals */
var source1 = Rx.Observable.interval(140)
    .map(function (i) { return 'First: ' + i; });

var source2 = Rx.Observable.interval(50)
    .map(function (i) { return 'Second: ' + i; });

// When source1 emits a value, combine it with the latest emission from source2.
var source = source1.withLatestFrom(
    source2,
    function (s1, s2) { return s1 + ', ' + s2; }
).take(4);

var subscription = source.subscribe(
    function (x) {
        console.log('Next: ' + x.toString());
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    },
    function () {
        console.log('Completed');
    });

// => Next: First: 0, Second: 1
// => Next: First: 1, Second: 4
// => Next: First: 2, Second: 7
// => Next: First: 3, Second: 10
// => Completed
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `forJoin` explains it:

> Runs all observable sequences in parallel and collect their last elements.

The *last* element I assume would be the last element fired before an observable completes, so all Observables that you pass to `forkJoin` has to be completed before anything is emitted.

Since you only want the first emitted element try to make each Observable complete after its first emit:

```
var source = Observable.forkJoin(
  this.af.database.object('tables').take(1),
  this.af.database.object('sections').take(1)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   var source = Observable.forkJoin(
      this.af.database.object('tables'),
      this.af.database.object('sections')
    );

var subscription = source.subscribe(
 data => {
       console.log(data[0]);
       console.log(data[1]);
      },
      err => console.error(err)
);
```